# In a random experiment, what is the probability of choosing a white but not black token?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So I and my friend had a argument on the following question:

A box contains 7 black colored, 14 white coloured and 9 yellow colored tokens. Now, if a random experiment is done, then what is the probability of choosing *a white token but not black token*?

Here is how I did:-

So i want to choose a (W)hite but(I can say '*and*' here WLG, Right?) not (B)lack token. It can symbolically be expressed as:

$W \cap \neg B $

$ \implies W \cap ( W \cup Y)$

$\implies (W \cap W) \cup (W \cap Y)$

$ \implies W $  ( because $ (W \cap Y) \subset W $ )

Which means n(Outcomes in favour) = 14.

$\therefore P(W \cap \neg B) = \frac{14}{30}$

But My friend did like this:

$P(W)=\frac{14}{30} , P(\neg B)=\frac{23}{30} $

$\implies P(W \cap \neg B)= \frac{14×23}{30×30} =\frac{161}{450}$

And now, after seeing him doing like this, I've become confused a little bit. So, I want to know which is correct. Help me be learned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But if it's White, it's automatically not Black, right? So "White but not Black" is just another way of saying "White", unless I have misunderstood what you mean by "experiment".

Comment: Doesn't "white but not black" simply mean "white"?

Comment: I strongly suspect that there is some sort of language difficulty here or you copied the problem incorrectly.  Perhaps you mean to ask the conditional probability problem "What is the probability that a randomly drawn token is white *given that the randomly drawn token isn't black*"?  That would have been $\frac{14}{23}$ however.

Comment: If you really do mean simply "White and Not black" then you did it correctly and your friend made a horrible mistake.  His mistake is simply that he believed that $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ in every scenario.  This is simply not true.  $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ is true if *and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  The events above clearly are not independent.  When the events are not independent then you actually have $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz wouldn't "What is the probability that a randomly drawn token is white given that the randomly drawn token isn't black?" be $\frac{14}{23}$?

Comment: If there had been multiple tokens samples then I would read *a white token, but not a black token* as meaning *all white or yellow, but not just all yellow* and done the calculation that way as 

$\mathbb P(\text{none black}) - \mathbb P(\text{all yellow}).$ 

With just one token this is $\frac{23}{30} - \frac{9}{30}=\frac{14}{30}$ which is the same as your more direct response

Comment: @TonyK that is why I did that way. I just expanded my thought with set theory to help you know If I'm going the right way

Comment: @JMoravitz, No language difficulty is there. The question was stated just like I've written here

Comment: @JMorvitz Yeah. Then It'd have been 14/23 because then black is already out of the scenario

Comment: @Paul: Sometimes set theory is the wrong way to go. Here, it just complicates a simple argument.

Comment: @TonyK I can't get you!! Then how should I do without using set or Venn diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the events $W$ and $\neg B$ and calculate the intersection rigrously:

1. $P(W \wedge \neg B)=P(W  )+P( \neg B)-P(W \vee \neg B)$

$P(W \wedge \neg B)=\frac{14}{30}+\frac{23}{30}-\frac{23}{30}=\frac{14}{30}$

2. $P(W \wedge \neg B)=P(W)\cdot P(\neg B|W)=\frac{14}{30}\cdot 1$

> $P(W)=\frac{14}{30} , P(\neg B)=\frac{23}{30} $
>
> $\implies P(W \wedge \neg B)=\frac{161}{450}$

Here your friend assumes independence of $W$ and $\neg B$. But this is not true.

$P(W)\cdot P(\neg B)\neq P(W \wedge \neg B)$

Comment: NO, my friend assumed these two events are independent, not me. And will you precisely say, what is the answer you're giving? 14/30 or 161/450?

Comment: The result is 14/30. Couldn´t you comprehend the two ways 1. and 2.?

Comment: No, i was actually confused on what you are saying is correct. By the way, what are you expressing by the symbol | (not B | A)?

Comment: $P(\neg B| W)$ is the probability that the chosen ball is not black given that the chosen ball is white.

Answer (score 0):

Any white token you choose is not black. You are indeed correct.

If your friend is being confused by you counting yellows, try to explain your reasoning to him. If he still doesn’t understand, use a Venn diagram. Remember you are interested in the value of $$|W \cap (S-B)|\over|S|$$

See the following (black region represents set $B$, white does $W$, blue does $Y$)

[image]

Obviously the coins only have one color each so the areas are disjoint.